# Disallowing the method change for every request in the web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, penetration-testing

Recently a project I am working on went through Penetration Testing. Testers provided a list of vulnerabilities in the application. There is one vulnerability saying **Change Request Method**. The description provided by them is as under,

We have discovered that the request method of the requests in the web application can be changed which means a security risk and can lead to a transfer of user credentials over the URL,
as can be seen in the following:

```
https://example.com/Default.aspx__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT'=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKLTUxNTc0NjE2QWBAIDD2QWAgIBD2QWBAIBD2QWAgIBD2QWA'mYPZBYGAgEPFgIeBFRleHQFCFVzZXJuYW1lZAIFDw8WBB4MRXJyb3JNZXNzYWdlBRRVc2VybmFtZSBpcyByZXF1aXJlZgVAwEcWAWZkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYCB'TtjdGwwMCRDbb2xkZXIxJGN0cmxUaXNMb2dpbiRMb2dpbkZvcm0kUmVtZW1iZXJNZQU8Y3RsMDAkQ29udGVudFBs'YWNlSG9sZJsVGlzTG9naW4kTG9naWrhZiPwphH4RdLXpZiwqV207%2Bw%3D&__VIEWSTAT'EGENERATOR=5812E479&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWCQK12eq2BgLlo5D%2FCQLps56DBALXz7ynBwLRmcB5As7B2rwIAseu8NIEA'tau8NIEAtmu8NIEUxmKcnm76NwQPNMZulPYvb76nhI%3D&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctrlMyLogin%24LoginForm%24'UserName=**test.name**%40mysite.com&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctrlmyLogin%24LoginForm%24Password=**testpassword**'&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ctrlmyLogin%24LoginForm%24LoginButton.x=35&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%2'4ctrlmyLogin%24LoginForm%24LoginButton.y=13&ctl00%24ctrlFooter%24ctrlLanguageSelector%24ddlLanguages=7
```

We recommend disallowing the method change for every request in the web
application.

I was able to reproduce this using the chrome extension named "Form Editor", an error is thrown "File Not Found". We do not support get requests. I no idea how to prevent Changing Method.

Little help would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://www.lanmaster53.com/2015/05/method-interchange/

Comment: In the article you provided it says "If the response mirrors that of the original request, then the application is vulnerable to Method Interchange.". This is not the case with my application, in fact there is an error for "File Not Found". So can I safely say that my application is not vulnerable to Method Interchange ?

Comment: I don't think so, @OP; you should ask the test provider for additional guidance on this threat

Comment: Will do that. Thanks.